# Buffer Observable Until Another Observable Completes

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactivex

I'm using RxSwift to wrap a mobile app's server sync process. I have an `Observable<RemoteEvent>` that wraps a websocket connection and emits each message received as an `Event`. Similarly, I have an `Observable<SynchronizationResult>` that wraps an API sync process. Once my application opens the WebSocket connection, the server sends a `hello` message. After that message is received, I want to start the sync process and buffer any events until the sync is completed. This is where I'm struggling. Currently, I have:

```
self.eventStreamService.observe(connection).scan((nil, [])) { (state, event) -> (Observable<RemoteEvent>?, [RemoteEvent]) in
  guard event.type == "hello" else {
    return (state.0?.concat(Observable.just(event)), state.1 + [event])
  }

  // This is the sync operation
  return (
    self.synchronizationService
      .synchronize(ConnectionSynchronizationContext(connection: connection), lightweight: true)
      .toArray()
      .flatMap { results -> Observable<RemoteEvent> in
        (state.1 + [event]).toObservable()
      },
    []
  )
}
.flatMapLatest { $0.0 ?? Observable.empty() }
```

Despite this being fairly ugly, it also has a significant bug: *any* incoming event results in the synchronization `Observable` being re-subscribed to, which then restarts the whole sync process. I'm sure there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: Will "hello" be the first event emitted by the websocket? If not, should any events prior to "hello" be buffered, or should it also buffer anything after "hello"/sync-start? This use case seems strange, but I'll ignore that and take it at face value since I assume you've altered your question to be a simple version of your actual use case.

Comment: @solidcell It's safe to assume that `hello` will be the first event. Anything before that (nothing, in practice) can be ignored. You're correct that this is both a strange use case, and also a simplified version of the problem. Ultimately, though, for the application I have this is the simplest way to prevent race conditions (for example, if the sync happens and then the websocket connects, events could be missed; if the websocket connects and syncs with no buffer, events could be processed before supporting data is available). This solution is mostly temporary until other issues are resolved.

Comment: How is it possible for this to be the case?: "if the sync happens and then the websocket connects".  If the websocket needs to connect in order for there to be a "hello" message so that we attempt to start a sync, then how could it ever be that a sync might happen before the websocket is connected?

Comment: Sorry I was explaining why this is the direction I went for now. It is correct that the websocket sends the hello and a sync happens after that. I was suggesting why I don't currently have it set up such that the sync happens before connecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could get the functionality you're looking for:

```
// this is a stub for the purpose of the example
let interval = Observable<Int>.interval(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
let websocketEvents = interval
    .map { i -> String in
        if i == 1 {
            return "hello"
        } else {
            return String(i)
        }
    }
    .replayAll()

websocketEvents.connect()

func performSync() -> Observable<Void> {
    return Observable<Void>.create { o in
        print("starting sync")
        // actually start sync with server
        // ....
        delay(2.0) {
            print("sync finished")
            o.onNext(())
        }
        return NopDisposable.instance
    }
}

// websocket events as they come, regardless of sync status
websocketEvents
    .subscribeNext { e in
        print("websocket event received: \(e)")
    }

// all websocket events, buffered and only emitted post-sync
websocketEvents
    .filter { $0 == "hello" }
    .flatMapLatest { _ in performSync() }
    .flatMapLatest { _ in websocketEvents }
    .subscribeNext { e in
        print("websocket event post sync: \(e)")
    }
```

This will output:

> websocket event received: 0
>   websocket event received: hello
>   starting sync
>   websocket event received: 2
>   websocket event received: 3
>   sync finished
>   websocket event post sync: 0
>   websocket event post sync: hello
>   websocket event post sync: 2
>   websocket event post sync: 3
>   websocket event received: 4
>   websocket event post sync: 4
>   websocket event received: 5
>   websocket event post sync: 5

Comment: This is awesome! One question - am I correct to assume that `replayAll` will continue to hold on to all items emitted from the stream, even when they've been played back? Are there concerns around the memory use here? My current (very hacky and broken) approach does impose a max size limit on the buffer and errors out the stream if it can't complete the sync before x entries are buffered (wasn't listed in the question for brevity)

Comment: Yea, it's definitely something to be concerned about.  There's `replay(bufferCount: Int)` which could limit the buffer size.  However, you should consider a different approach to your sync situation instead of buffering elements at all, if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As for the sync, I've toyed with a few different approaches. The one I'm the biggest fan of has the server keeping a cache of events for the last x duration. Then on connection it just dumps everything you missed, so there's no additional work for the client to do. The problem is that (depending on the app and types of events) this can result in significantly more data usage than making API calls.